# How does relativity explain gravity, without assuming gravity

Tags: gravity, spacetime, relativity

I have seen the "objects pull down on space-time" explanations, but they assume a "pull down" force themselves. Could anyone explain the space-time explanation without assuming gravity in the first place?

[image]

Comment: 5-dimensional gravity distorts the 4-dimensional space-time where 3-dimensional objects sitting. ;)
But this 5-dimensional gravitational acceleration is constant.

Comment: "They distort it because they are pulled down by .. what?" :- They are not "pulled down" by anything. Its just that energy interacts with spacetime as per Einstein's equation and makes it curved.

Comment: Are you asking why massive objects distort spacetime? I'm not sure, but your question is more a kind of philosophic question. Physicist don't know anything about "why", they know a little bit about "how".

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16925/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7781/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51198/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26440/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57256/.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you want to assume gravity? Gravity it is an experimental fact, a starting point for doing physics. General Relativy is a geometrical theory of gravity, built on the basis of Special Relativity and always having in mind that it should recover the non-relativistic Newtonian theory of the gravitational field.

The "pull down" is a deviation of the flat, Minkowski spacetime, governed by the Einstein Field equations. And in my opinion a not-so-good analogy because it is rather difficult to imagine how to pull down time.

Answer (score 3):

> but they assume a "pull down" force themselves.

The images of flat sheets "pulled down" where the planets are do not reflect the fact that the curvature of spacetime is an *intrinsic* curvature that is measured by geodesic deviation.

What has been done, in order to help *visualize* the spatial curvature, is to take a two dimensional spatial slice and then embed that into a fictional, flat 3D space where the intrinsic curvature of the slice is represented as an *extrinsically* curved 2D surface.

A good example of how this is done for a spherically symmetric static star can be found in the book "Gravitation" on page 613:

> Therefore, depict 3-space only as it is at one time, *t = constant*. 
>   Moreover, at any one time the space itself has spherical symmetry. 
>   Consequently, one slice through the center, $r=0$, that divides the
>   space symmetrically into two halves (for example, the equatorial
>   slice, $\theta = \pi/2$ ) has the same 2-geometry as any other such
>   slice (any selected angle of tilt, at any azimuth) through the center. 
>   Therefore limit attention to the 2-geometry of the equatorial slice. 
>   The geometry on this slice is described by the line element
>
> $$ds^2 = [1-2m(r)/r]^{-1}dr^2 + r^2d\phi^2.$$
>
> Now one may embed this two-dimensional curved-space geometry in the
>   flat geometry of a Euclidean three-dimensional manifold.

Read more using [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=w4Gigq3tY1kC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=embedding%20diagram&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

Massive objects distort spacetime, as described by the [Einstein Field Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations). In turn, this causes particles to accelerate: the GR equivalent of $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$ are the **geodesic equations**:
$$
\frac{\text{d}^2x^\alpha}{\text{d}\lambda^2} + \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}\frac{\text{d}x^\mu}{\text{d}\lambda}\frac{\text{d}x^\nu}{\text{d}\lambda} = 0,\qquad \alpha=0,\ldots 4,
$$
with
$$
\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}
    \left(\frac{\partial g_{\beta\mu}}{\partial x^\nu} + 
      \frac{\partial g_{\beta\nu}}{\partial x^\mu} - 
      \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\beta}\right),
$$
the so-called **Christoffel symbols**, and $g_{\mu\nu}(x^\alpha)$ the spacetime metric. In the absence of matter, $g_{\mu\nu}(x^\alpha)$ is constant, so that the geodesic equations reduce to
$$
\frac{\text{d}^2x^\alpha}{\text{d}\lambda^2} = 0,
$$
which describe a constant motion, as expected.