# How is Space-Time curved?

Tags: general-relativity, soft-question

How does space-time curved by mass/energy if there's nothing to be curved? I haven't seen any satisfying answer.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what the question is, but surely if you stop thinking of spacetime as "nothing", the perceived problem will evaporate in a puff of logic. After all, spacetime has definite properties (e.g., number of dimensions) even before we get to discussing its geometry.

Comment: How does mass curve vacuum? The properties of spacetime  doesn't explain what exactly is being curved?

Comment: I think it would be hard to truly understand this unless you understand the mathematical notion of curvature; to what extent do you know differential geometry?  If you haven't yet learned about curvature in the context of differential geometry, then it's not surprising that you've asked this question because, a la @StanLiou's comment; it's otherwise hard to describe what sort of object spacetime actually "is" and how such a thing can be curved.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but may be helpful motivation. The universe is the quantum fields (electromagnetic, gluon, quark and so forth) that make it up. "Empty" space (more precisely, a vaccum) is simply a neighbourhood in the universe where all these fields are in their ground state. The fields are all still there. I think it will help if you ponder on the notion that there are these fields and *nothing else*: "empty" and "vacuum" are simply words that come from an era when our whole lives were filled up looking for food, shelter and looking after the little ones: now we must reinterpret these ...

Comment: ...words in the light of what we know of the World that was unseen by our forebears.

Comment: You should investigate the difference between intrinsic and extrinsic curvature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Here's a useful link.*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3009/5223) For me, it's helpful to think there are clocks and rulers. The clock I have is the only one I have to measure time, and the ruler I have is the only one I have to measure distance, but you can think of space as being spanned by a big lattice of rulers, and if some of them get shortened or lengthened relative to others, there's no way for the people next to them to know it, but the whole lattice is being bent, and a similar thing is happening to clocks.