# If strong gravitational fields bend and slow down time, how can travelling near the speed of light do the same?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, speed-of-light

I was wondering how travelling near the speed of light could slow down time, seeing that light approaching a strong gravitational field would get curved and therefore reach its destination in a longer amount of time.

I may be misunderstanding what i have read, but i thought that time and light acted similarly when it came to gravitational fields.

So, if light is slowed down, shouldn't time also be slowed down?
So, why would travelling at the high speed of light also slow down time?

Comment: Related; If you read this, it might be a help http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192318/can-anyone-explain-me-how-time-can-bend-according-to-einstein-in-simple-way?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Speed of light can slow down just like a jet slows down to land through friction and gravity the change in direction through the cosmos. 
After all light is energy and has to deplete sometime
Time is constant and the more or less time it takes for the light to travel determine the speed
I always think as time being faster than light, how else can light be timed, if time isn't already at the finish line to see how fast the light is.