# Does the space curvature want it to become flat?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

I've read that mass bends the fabric of space. So does space want this curvature to become flat? I know it's a different question. but I think some systems still want to come back to normal.

Does this fabric interact with the mass to return to flat? (maybe in secret), Does this fabric have a limit?

[image: General_Relativity]

Comment: This is a problem with all analogies - they fail when pushed too far...

Comment: It makes sense, after all, Newton's first law also wants to keep its state. Such is the case with the curvature of space.

Comment: Space is not deformed, its curved in initial state...

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of: [How space regains its neutral shape in the absence of massive objects?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/636137/) (Related: note by Kirk T. McDonald, titled '[what is the stiffness of spacetime?](http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/stiffness.pdf)'

Comment: No, the fabric doesn't want to be flat. You need an iron to iron the curves out.

Comment: and starch. Mustn't forget the starch.